# How to mount ceiling light with mounting holes too wide?

Tags: light-fixture

The standard distance between electric box holes is 3.5", while the holes on the light are 3.65".  It makes little sense and I don't have a mounting bracket that has holes or slots that can accommodate.  Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a bracket, so, you need to get a bracket or adapter plate that accommodates the holes you are working with (they are common) or you have to replace the box with a box that has the hole spacing required (more work, generally.)

Round boxes, octagon boxes and square boxes all tend to have different hole spacings, so it's not unusual to have spacing that does not match the fixture directly on the box.

[image: Two adapters for light fixtures]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aconcordcarpenter.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F07%2FReplacing-an-outdoor-light-fixture-6-600x400.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=add3f941da4eae852ad217d30aa5a9f18ca9616c8aa2ee22f6bcc3c63341dea7&ipo=images) no affiliation*

Comment: Ahh, so the catch here is that all these brackets I have are not wide enough.  I thought that was the limit.  There are some round styles out there that are wider.  Thanks!